# PushWoosh Error : status code : 210 status_message: application code is not valid

Tags: java, android, pushwoosh

I am trying to request on pushwoosh services using API but it's returning me following response (Form Pushwoosh service) :

```
[RequestManager] ERROR: {"status_code":210,"status_message":"application code is not valid","response":null}
```

Also I have a meta-data in ManifestFile.

How can I fix it?
Thanks for help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed. I replaced the appid into "XXXXX-XXXXXX" in Manifest

```
<meta-data android:name="com.pushwoosh.appid" android:value="XXXXX-XXXXX" />
```